# WatchService watch specfic directory for creation of files

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {
        Path _directotyToWatch = Paths.get(args[0]);
        WatchService watcherSvc = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        WatchKey watchKey = _directotyToWatch.register(watcherSvc, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
        while (true) {
            watchKey=watcherSvc.take();
            for (WatchEvent<?> event: watchKey.pollEvents()) {
                WatchEvent<Path> watchEvent = castEvent(event);
                System.out.println(event.kind().name().toString() + " " + _directotyToWatch.resolve(watchEvent.context()));
                watchKey.reset();
            }
        }
    }
```

In above example the watch directory path is taken from console arguments.
I want to pass the directory path statically.

Tried this Paths.get("O:\\test"); but throws exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/file/Paths
    at JSR203_NIO2_WatchFolder.main(JSR203_NIO2_WatchFolder.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.nio.file.Paths
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
```

Comment: `Paths.get("O:\test");`  I doubt that would compile - 'illegal escape character'.

Comment: its   
 
Paths.get("O:\\test")

Comment: What's the output of `java -version`?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Path _directotyToWatch = Paths.get("O:/test");
```

Comment: What Java Version are you using? Java.nio..package is a part of Java 7,  try to check your version maby you have a lower version of java.

Comment: It seems the class defninition is missing, i would try to reinstall the package and try again, the documentation says: This Exception is thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no definition of the class could be found.
The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into that problem and I think what you want is:

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(path_string);
```